# What is the sound quality of the blue-marble vinyl pressing of Electric Youth's "Innerworld"?

Tags: vinyl, sound-quality, audio-quality

does anyone have a take on the sound quality of the blue-marble vinyl pressing of Electric Youth's "Innerworld" album? I've been interested in buying one on eBay for some time but with the high price I would like to know how well it plays. Especially trying to avoid sibilance. Thanks!

Comment: How are you objectively quantifying "sound quality" here?

Comment: I admit I'm not familiar with a way to quantify sound quality. If you have an opinion of how this pressing sounds, I'd love to know!

Comment: No, I don't, sorry, but I can tell you the blue marble won't make it sound any better ;)
My advice: buy hi-res wavs and EQ to your liking. If you want the vinyl sound-colouring and satisfaction of watching it spin, get the vinyl and EQ to your liking. Vinyl is a good investment anyway. I have stuff from the 90's worth a lot now.